# How to install Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I've been trying to install Jekyll for two days now but don't understand why it doesn't work.

I've updated my ruby development environment and have homebrew and bundler installed.

When I type `gem install jekyll` it seems to work, but when I try to use jekyll, it doesn't work

```
macs-MBP-2:~ mac$ which ruby
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
macs-MBP-2:~ mac$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin17]
macs-MBP-2:~ mac$ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-2.0.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.0.2
Done installing documentation for bundler after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
macs-MBP-2:~ mac$ gem install jekyll
Successfully installed jekyll-3.8.6
Parsing documentation for jekyll-3.8.6
Done installing documentation for jekyll after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
macs-MBP-2:~ mac$ jekyll new
-bash: jekyll: command not found


macs-MBP-2:~ mac$ gem info jekyll    
*** LOCAL GEMS ***    
jekyll (3.8.6)
    Author: Tom Preston-Werner
    Homepage: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll
    License: MIT
    Installed at: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
    A simple, blog aware, static site generator.

macs-MBP-2:~ mac$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Users/mac/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

Comment: Please show `gem info jekyll` and `echo $PATH`.

Comment: OK. I am having a hard time just adding this stuff and formatting it properly <i>*sigh*</i> but I added it to my original post!

Comment: Your `jekyll` executable should be in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin`, I believe. Adding that directory to the `PATH` should allow you to run it. Or you can run it directly as `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/jekyll`.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using a ruby version manager, so that's one reasons you might see path errors like this. Highly recommend picking one (asdf + asdf-ruby, rvm, rbenv are my favorites in order). With a ruby version manager it should set the paths and such relatively automatically. If you type `which jekyll` you should see that it's not in any of the paths you listed, so you'll need to add it per @Amadan

Comment: OK thanks for the recommendations I will try it! If I want to learn more about how to add directories to the PATH is this a good link? http://osxdaily.com/2014/08/14/add-new-path-to-path-command-line/
feel free to suggest another resource I was just googling :)